# PRAW: get_submission works inconsistently

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

The script gets the information from a specific comment on Reddit.
It will work or not depending on the permalink given to it.

```
import praw
from pprint import pprint
clipboard = ['permalink']
com = r.get_submission(clipboard).comments[0]
pprint(vars(com))
```

This permalink works : http://www.reddit.com/r/redditgetsdrawn/comments/1tvjmr/i_got_a_new_job_recently_and_would_love_to_have/cec9wh4

This one doesn't : http://www.reddit.com/r/redditgetsdrawn/comments/1ts9hi/surprise_me_thanks_in_advance/cec0897?context=3

I have the feeling that the permalinks ending with ?context=3 or other unusual ends have particular characteristics that screw up the .get_submission.

Here's the error report :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\Scripts\brdg\brdg.py", line 14, in <module>
    com = r.get_submission(clipboard).comments[0]
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 875, in get_submission
    comment_sort=comment_sort)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\decorators.py", line 320, in wrapped
    return function(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\objects.py", line 837, in from_url
    s_info, c_info = reddit_session.request_json(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\decorators.py", line 158, in wrapped
    return_value = function(reddit_session, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 476, in request_json
    response = self._request(url, params, data)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 338, in _request
    cache_key = (normalize_url(request.url), tuple(key_items))
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\helpers.py", line 140, in normalize_url
    if url.endswith('.json'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

**Edit:** Here's what i get when i change the list to a string :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 368, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\Scripts\brdg\brdg.py", line 14, in <module>
    com = r.get_submission(clipboard).comments[0]
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 875, in get_submission
    comment_sort=comment_sort)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\decorators.py", line 320, in wrapped
    return function(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\objects.py", line 837, in from_url
    s_info, c_info = reddit_session.request_json(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\decorators.py", line 158, in wrapped
    return_value = function(reddit_session, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 483, in request_json
    data = json.loads(response, object_hook=hook)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 332, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 352, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Aymeric\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 370, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

**Edit2:** It's now working if i remove *?context=3* and change the list to a string. Apparently, it never worked as a list anyway (my bad memory got in there !), and *?context=3* seems to be the problem.

Comment: The error is saying that you are trying to call the `endswith()` function using a list. It is a string function.

Comment: But then why does it work fine with other links, still as a list ? I get another error report when i change the link to a string, i'll edit it in the OP.

Comment: This could potentially be a bug with the module. Instead of `var.endswith(val)` try `if var[-1] == val:`

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to change, there is no var.endswith(val) for me to replace. Also in the full script get_submission has a string as argument, i suppose it works here because the list has only one element ?

Comment: Apparently i was wrong i my first response : it doesn't seem to work at all with lists. I don't know how i thought otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that `?context=3` and the answer is simply that PRAW didn't support url parameters at the time of your question. It does now with PRAW 2.1.13 or later. Upgrade your version of PRAW with `pip install praw -U` .

Your thought that `get_submission` took a list as an argument, probably comes from confusing it with  [`get_submissions`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/code_overview.html#praw.__init__.UnauthenticatedReddit.get_submissions) method, which does take an iterable as an argument.